# Does anyone know why this jquery doesn't work in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Can anyone tell me why this jQuery doesn't work in IE8? It works fine in Chrome but not in IE.

```js
$(document).ready (function() {
  $('.first-p').hide();   
  $( "div.first" ).click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle(1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="first">Toggle first</div>
<p class="first-p">First hidden paragraph.</p>
<div class="first">Toggle second</div>
<p class="first-p">Second hidden paragraph.</p>
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as per Jquery page state

If you need to support older browsers like Internet Explorer 6-8, Opera 12.1x or Safari 5.1+, use jQuery 1.12.

you using 3.2.1 version